# How do I use wtforms RadioField input to add an option with open-ended text input option?

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

How can I use wtforms / flask_wtf to render an HTML form:

- with a select field that gives the responder fixed choices, plus
- an "Other" option that allows them to enter text.

I'm using the RadioField to get the particular choices, but I don't see how to add an open ended text box to the selection choices.

Is there any way to do this without hacking the code?

Answer (score 0):

It's basically s SelectField plus a TextField.
You just need to handle that on the server side. If you want, you can use some javascript in order to show/hide this extra textfield using your radio button.

Information about the different widgets available here: http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/widgets.html

Comment: Could you please give an exmple of how you would implement that?
You say "SelectField plus a TextField" but I don't understand what you mean by that "plus" operator. One would have to somehow couple the the contents of the SelectField to those of the TextField.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I haven't used wtforms in years.

I don't remember how any of this works now, but i'm guessing you need to create 2 fields, one selectfield, and one text field. The same as if you were dealing with 2 textfields really. The widgets (IIRC) are just the html representation of a field. But you can use different widgets for the same fields. Hope this makes sense